# Sorting list of objects by NextObjectId

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of objects that have properties Id and `NextObjectId`. `NextObjectId` is referring to `Id` of another object telling to that object it is supposed to be after the object it's referring to. Object `Id`s are random and not in any particular order.

Can you show the most efficient way how to organize list of objects from random order to ascending according to `NextObjectId`?

Comment: Which object would you want to be the first one in the result?

Comment: You need to give an example input, output + what you've tried. Although,I suspect Daisy's answer is more or less what you want..

Comment: Give a look at my answer

Comment: See my answer, it might be what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is.

If I understood you right, you have a class like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? NextObjectId { get; set; }
}
```

and  `List<MyObject>` like this one:

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = new List<MyObject>
    {
        new MyObject {Id = 5, NextObjectId = 4},//4
        new MyObject {Id = 4, NextObjectId = 1},//5
        new MyObject {Id = 2, NextObjectId = 87},//1
        new MyObject {Id = 70, NextObjectId = 5},//3
        new MyObject {Id = 1, NextObjectId = null},//6
        new MyObject {Id = 87, NextObjectId = 70}//2
    };
```

Since the `NextObjectId` refers to the next object's `Id`, then there must be a `NextObjectId` with `null` (or zero), that is the last element, and the item before it is the before last element which its `NextObjectId`'s value equals to the last element's `Id`. We can build the method `OrderChain` on this algorithm:

```
private static IEnumerable<MyObject> OrderChain(List<MyObject> myObjects)
    {
        var starter = myObjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NextObjectId == null);
        yield return starter;
        var count = myObjects.Count;
        while (count > 1)
        {
            yield return GetCurrent(myObjects, ref starter);
            count--;
        }
    }

private static MyObject GetCurrent(List<MyObject> lst, ref MyObject current)
    {
        var id = current.Id;
        current = lst.SingleOrDefault(x => x.NextObjectId == id);
        return current;
    }
```

Then you can sort it like this:

```
 var myOrderedObjects = OrderChain(myObjects).Reverse().ToList();
```

this gives me this list:

```
{ Id = 2, NextObjectId = 87 },//1
{ Id = 87, NextObjectId = 70 },//2
{ Id = 70, NextObjectId = 5 },//3
{ Id = 5, NextObjectId = 4 },//4
{ Id = 4, NextObjectId = 1 },//5
{ Id = 1, NextObjectId = null }//6
```

Answer (score 2):

I made this algorithm. It should do what you wanted to:

```
class Program
{
    private static Random random = new Random();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //GENERATE A RANDOM LIST FOR THE EXAMPLE
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        int? lastID = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            int id = random.Next();
            items.Add(new Item() { ID = id, NextItemID = lastID });
            lastID = id;
        }
        //GENERATE A RANDOM LIST FOR THE EXAMPLE

        items = items.OrderBy(x => random.Next()).ToList(); //SHUFFLE THE LIST FOR THE EXAMPLE


        items.OrderByNextItemID(); //SORT THE LIST BY NextItemID
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void OrderByNextItemID(this List<Item> items)
    {
        List<Item> results = new List<Item>();
        Item item = items.Where(x => x.NextItemID == null).First();
        results.Add(item);
        items.Remove(item);
        int length = items.Count;
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            item = items.Where(x => x.NextItemID == results.Last().ID).FirstOrDefault();
            if(item != null)
            {
                results.Add(item);
                items.Remove(item);
            }
        }
        results.Reverse();
        items.AddRange(results);
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? NextItemID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you in the correct way, you have the following relation:
A.Id = B.NextObjectId && B.Id != A.Id.

So you need to sort by Id with Linq.

```
IEnumerable<AClass> orderedObjects = objects.OrderBy(e => e.Id);
```

Or if you want to sort by NextObjectId

```
IEnumerable<AClass> orderedObjects = objects.OrderBy(e => e.NextObjectId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply create a dictionary from its object ID to the object. From there, assuming you have a starting object and some way of finishing (e.g. a `NextObjectId` of null) you can just build the list up. It's not particularly LINQ-based, but it *is* simple:

```
YourType item = ...; // Whatever should come first.
var map = objects.ToDictionary(obj => obj.ObjectId);
var list = new List<YourType>();
list.Add(item);
while (item.NextObjectId != null)
{
    // TODO: Handle missing objects? (Use TryGetValue instead of the indexer)
    item = map[item.NextObjectId];
    list.Add(item);
}
```